# how to get logged in user name in mediaWiki before the page is rendered?

Tags: php, mediawiki

hello i am hacking ApprovedRevs mediaWiki extension I am using mediaWiki 1.16

basically i need to know the name of current logged in user in mediaWiki in a function which is executed when an UnknownAction hook is fired,

I know i can access the logged in user name $wgUser->mName; $wgUser being a global variable but what i get is an empty string

I did print_r in skin file (vector.php) and it contained all the info there but when i did the same in the function i am working on i got this:

```
StubUser Object
(
    [mGlobal] => wgUser
    [mClass] => 
    [mParams] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

i.e it was empty so can anyone tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the object's `getName` method (like `$wgUser->getName()`) instead of accessing the property directly.

This is because the object is initially a *stub object*. This means that the data aren't loaded until the first method call. You can see the reference documentation on [`StubObject`](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classStubObject.html).